# Draw specified Object Inspector into Rect

Tags: unity-game-engine, draw

I was wondering if there was any method for drawing a default inspector for a given object into a `Rect`, similar to the other GUI methods?

I'm looking for a simple way of drawing various inspectors for linked objects into a custom `EditorWindow`.

I had tried to instance the specific editor as of course that contains `DrawDefaultIspector`, but I just get masses of exceptions from inside `SerializePropertyBindings`.

Is there a method to draw the default inspector for a given object?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution to this using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054955/unity-custom-inspector-on-custom-window).

I just want to show the default inspector, so I can create an instance of a base Editor then fire `OnInspectorGUI()` in my `EditorWindow.OnGUI()` code:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    Editor editor = Editor.CreateEditor(this.linkedObject);
    editor.OnInspectorGUI();
}
```

(Obviously I should probably only recreate that editor when the linkedObject changes, but just for the sake of clarity.)

Doesn't allow me to draw into a `Rect`, but I assume I can cover that requirement with a scroll panel or similar.